# why instance variables are not mandatory to be final in anonymous class with multithreading in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In this code snippet why java does not generate compile time error when there is potential of getting error.
In the below snippet I try to access an instance variable inside a new thread and in the main thread i change the value to null.
Is it intentionally not made to give compilation error?

```
public class AnonymousClass {

    private Object str = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnonymousClass ac = new AnonymousClass();
        ac.testMultiThreading();
    }

    public void testMultiThreading() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("string value " + str.toString());
            }
        });
        System.out.println("value of str before changing " + str.toString());
        str = null;
        t.start();
        System.out.println("value of str after changing " + str.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why you'd think that would result in a compilation error. I have no idea why you think the anonymous class has anything to do with anything. I also have no idea why you think setting `str` to `null` would affect anything (besides setting `str` to `null` of course).

Comment: Why would this give you a compilation error? A ``NullPointerException`` during runtime, yes. But you can change variables from any thread you want. Making that error-safe is up to you.

Comment: I got this question while defining a local variable in testMultiThreading and using inside the run, and which gives me compilation error "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable name defined in an enclosing scope".

Comment: @NitishSingla a local variable inside a method and an instance variable behave differently. You are not supposed to be able to change local variables from another thread. That's why they have to be final.

Comment: @f1sh Thanks, can you point me to some link stating side effects in case local variables were allowed to change.

Comment: @NitishSingla that doesnt exist. Local variables only live in the scope of the method. Making them final is supposed to give read-only access to a thread that is also created in that method.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the program from Java's point of view:

- Your program accesses `str` from three places in the code, all of which have visibility of it. This is legal
- Your program is not required to `null` test objects before calling `toString` on them, and it is going to get a `NullPointerException` if `str` happens to be `null`
- Java compiler is not in a position to analyze thread safety of your program. It is programmer's responsibility.

Your program may have a number of reasons for changing the value of an instance variable concurrently. For example, a thread may want to compute some value, and put the result into an instance variable for the main thread to harvest. Java gives you synchronization tools for doing it safely. Therefore, there is no reason for Java compiler to insist on the instance variables to be `final`.